# Error when creating materialized view on datastream enabled Bigquery tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, materialized-views, google-datastream

We have tables in bigquery that are populated using datastream from postgres. We want to create materialized views on top of these bigquery tables but we run into the following error

**Materialized views has a base table with unapplied Change Data Capture(CDC) upsert data within a configured period.**

Comment: An answer by Google: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/BigQuery-table-using-DataStream-gives-CDC-error/m-p/543771#M1444

Comment: @JohnHanley I did see the article but I do not understand exactly how it can be solved. I have played around with the refresh_interval_minutes and max_staleness options but I haven't been able to figure out what they mean by CDC config or replication lag options.

Comment: Hi @codechef, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, please let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this **[PIT issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/277500817#comment4)** and this public **[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-data-capture#limitations)**, materialized views over the BigQuery table that has upsert data is not supported. The **[Change Data Capture](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-data-capture)**(CDC) is used to update the BigQuery tables by processing and applying streamed changes to existing data which is also called as upserting the data. Since the MV’s over the table that has upsert data is not supported, you are getting the error.

However, there is a **[feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/275376935)** filed for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking **`+1`** and **`STAR`** mark to receive updates on it.